# Extract substring using sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have a log file of the following:

```
example.com - - - 127.0.01 [22/Sep/2013:07:22:22 +0000]  "POST /api/test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 355 "-" "-" "{\x22id\x22:\x22 ... }}}"

example.com - - - 127.0.01 [22/Sep/2013:07:22:22 +0000]  "POST /api/test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 355 "-" "-" "{\x22id\x22:"{\x22 ... }}}"
```

I want to extract the first `{\x22` to the last `}`

So I am using the following sed command:

```
cat test.txt  | sed -r  's/.+?"(\{.+\})".*/\1/g'
```

However, it give me

```
{\x22id\x22:\x22 ... }}}

{\x22 ... }}}
```

But I want

```
{\x22id\x22:\x22 ... }}}

{\x22id\x22:"{\x22 ... }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `.+?` doesn't work with `sed` since its regex engine doesn't support non-greedy matching.

However if you consider perl it is possible:

```
perl -pe 's/.+?"(\{.+\})".*/\1/g' test.txt
{\x22id\x22:\x22 ... }}}
{\x22id\x22:"{\x22 ... }}}
```

**OR using `egrep -o`:**

```
egrep -o '\{.+\}' test.txt
{\x22id\x22:\x22 ... }}}
{\x22id\x22:"{\x22 ... }}}
```

Comment: You can also use grep with the perl engine activated. `grep -P` or `pgrep`. The command would then be `cat test.txt | grep -P -o "<regex pattern>"`

Comment: @ffledgling: Thanks, updated answer, yes `egrep` will also work same as `grep -P`

Comment: The difference b/w `egrep` or `grep -E` and `grep -P` is the regex engine they use. `egrep` is `ERE` and `pgrep` is Perl's engine. Though I've never seen much difference practically. (Note pgrep and grep -P are not the same, sorry for the confusion)

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/[^{]*{/,"{");sub(/}"/,"}")}1' file
{\x22id\x22:\x22 ... }}}

{\x22id\x22:"{\x22 ... }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cut="#CuT#"
sed -n --posix "s/\({\\\\x22.*}\)\"$/${Cut}\1/;s/.*${Cut}//p" sample.txt
```

I use a variable Cut to change with any other "marker" depending what is in text to treat. The variale is not needed itself and you could directly change its content in the sed if you are sure the value of Cut is not in the file

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\({\\x22.*}\).*/\n\1/;s/.*\n//' file
```

Greed is your enemy in the first match so use the divide-and-conquer idiom for the `{\x22`. That is place a unique marker (in this case `\n`) and use a second substitute command to remove the first part of the string. For the last `}` greed is your friend as `.*}` will find the last match by itself.

N.B. If the first match were a single character, say `X` then a negated character class `[^X]*` would be suffice. However as it is a string (two or more characters) this will not work.