# Execution of a sed command in comma separated pattern-addresses when the second pattern is not matched

Tags: regex, bash, sed, git-bash

In  comma separated pattern-addresses, if sed matches both patterns, it will execute the related command for the matched lines and the lines in the middle. Therefore:

```
sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p'  < foo
```

will print all lines between `pattern1` and `pattern2`  and the matching lines themselves.

If `pattern1` is not matched the command will not execute, i.e. nothing will be printed.
But, if it is `pattern2` to be unmatched, the command will execute (the lines will be printed) up to the end of the file!

Is it possible to avoid execution also when `pattern2` is unmatched?

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
sed -n /pattern1/{:a;N;/pattern2/!ba;p;} < foo
```

(GNU `sed` only)

Note that `pattern2` must not contain `^` or `$` for this to work as the `N` command concatenates all lines into one large, `\n`-delimited string. Constructs like `/^Something/` must be replaced with `/\nSomething`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but since you can't decide whether to print until you've seen the whole pattern you have to buffer the input:

```
sed -n '/pattern1,/pattern2/{H;/pattern2/{g;s/.//p}}'
```

Comment: i suggest for the last s/ to use s/./&/p to avoid missing some part of the content in output

Comment: so add ^. or ^\n due  to different behavior of sed dependong of the version and OS. I often use 1h;1!H to avoid this but your version is smarter and certainly quicker

Comment: There's a sed where `s/x//` won't delete the first `x`?

Comment: I don't know, haven't see but not tested all :-D, I just know that depending of implementation behavior change like taking a group (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971628/extract-substring-using-sed/19972206#19972206)